How can I export vector layers to a spreadsheet in the Qgis model designer with a conditional branch algorithm?
I made a model that extract vector layers and export the attributes into a spreadsheet. It's completely functional.
But when I add a conditional branch algorithm to choose if I want to use or not an input it doesn't work anymore except if I choose "yes" for each input ; but if I choose "No" for one of my possible inputs the model doesn't export data into a spreadsheet.
I tried to add some dependencies but with no success.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks
model

If I choose "No" for the input "city" and "Yes" for" the input "department" I get no spreadsheet at all
If I choose "yes" for the input "city" and "Yes" for" the input "department" I get a spreadsheet

I expect to get a spreadsheet, even if I choose only one of the inputs.
The problem is that the algorithm "Export to a spreadsheet" is the last of the model and I can't find a solution to "tell" it: "it's not a problem if there's only one input that has been chosen."
